# basis solution set, orthogonal complement

Tags: matrices

> *The equation $x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}-x_{4}=0$ is in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$. Give a basis for the solution set $V\subset\mathbb{R}^{4}$ of this
>   equation. Give a basis for the orthogonal complement $V^{\perp}$.
>   Write the vector $\left(\begin{matrix}1\\ 1\\ 1\\ 1\end{matrix}\right)$ 
>   as a sum of vector $v\in V$ and a vector $w\in V^{\perp}$*

My attempt:

$x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}=x_{4}$

$\left(\begin{matrix}x_{1}\\ x_{2}\\ x_{3}\\ x_{4}\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}x_{1}\\ x_{2}\\ x_{3}\\ x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}\end{matrix}\right)=x_{1}\cdot\left(\begin{matrix}1\\ 0\\ 0\\ 1\end{matrix}\right)+x_{2}\cdot\left(\begin{matrix}0\\ 1\\ 0\\ 1\end{matrix}\right)+x_{3}\cdot\left(\begin{matrix}0\\ 0\\ 1\\ 1\end{matrix}\right)$

So a basis for the solution set is:
$\lbrace\left(\begin{matrix}1\\ 0\\ 0\\ 1\end{matrix}\right),\left(\begin{matrix}0\\ 1\\ 0\\ 1\end{matrix}\right),\left(\begin{matrix}0\\ 0\\ 1\\ 1\end{matrix}\right)\rbrace$.

The orthongal complement of the solution set: $Nul A=(Row A)^{\perp}$

So a basis for the $V^{\perp}$ is:

$\lbrace\left(\begin{matrix}1\\ 0\\ 0\end{matrix}\right),\left(\begin{matrix}0\\ 1\\ 0\end{matrix}\right),\left(\begin{matrix}0\\ 0\\ 1\end{matrix}\right)\rbrace$.

But how can i write the vector $\left(\begin{matrix}1\\ 1\\ 1\\ 1\end{matrix}\right)$ 
 as a sum of vector $v\in V$ and a vector $w\in V^{\perp}$? I tried reducing the augmented matrix below, but that doesn't seem to work..

$\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\end{matrix}\right)$

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is a matrix and $Ax=0$ a system of linear equations with solution space $V$, then $V^{\perp}=row(A)$, where $row(A)$ is the space spanned by the rows of $A$. In your case we have $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1&1&1&-1 \end{pmatrix}$, so $V^{\perp}=\{\begin{pmatrix} t&t&t&-t \end{pmatrix}^T:t\in \Bbb R\}$. You therefore need to solve$$\begin{pmatrix} t\\t\\t\\-t \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_1+x_2+x_3 \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} 1\\1\\1\\1 \end{pmatrix}$$ This is a simple system of linear equations.

Comment: So my basis is incorrect?

Comment: Your basis for $V$ is correct, but your basis for $V^{\perp}$ is incorrect. Note that $V^{\perp}$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^4$ and your basis consists of vectors from $\Bbb R^3$.